# How to save an image in postgres bytea field in ascii encoding with django

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to save an image in django by converting it to base64 and saving it to 'bytea' field in postgresql. I've managed to do it, but the string is encoded in UTF8. Is there a way I could encode to ascii just for this field?

Here's my code for a custom Base64 model field:

```
import base64
from django.db import models

class Base64Field(models.TextField):

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        if self.db_column is None:
            self.db_column = name
        self.field_name = name + '_base64'
        super(Base64Field, self).contribute_to_class(cls, self.field_name)
        setattr(cls, name, property(self.get_data, self.set_data))

    def get_data(self, obj):
        #return obj.data_base64 #this works if the image is ascii-encoded
        return base64.b64decode(getattr(obj, self.field_name)) #this also works well with the setter below

    def set_data(self, obj, data):
        setattr(obj, self.field_name, base64.encodestring(data)) #is encoded to UTF8

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'longtext'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Either* use a `text` field with base64-encoded text, *or* store the binary data in a `bytea` field. Don't store base64-encoded binary in a `bytea` field, that's just confusing.

I recommend using `bytea` and `bytea_output = 'hex'` (default in 9.0 and above).

Comment: saving binary directly to bytea is a good idea indeed. this class helped me do it: https://github.com/niwibe/django-orm-extensions/blob/master/django_orm/postgresql/fields/bytea.py